# Authentication silverlight to .NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, silverlight, migration

So my first project at this new company is to convert a silverlight project to HTML5.  I get mostly done with it but then in gets down to the nitty gritty.  I have a legacy database.  I essentially recycled the backend and made a client-side SPA solution using HTML5/CSS/Javascript.  I come from an Apple/Linux background, so .NET is super new to me.  I have learned that it's generally good to ditch the command line and let windows take control.  Either ways, here's the problem.  I figured out how to query this Pronto DB, and realized the passwords are hashed as they should be, but the mechanism that encrypted them client side was probably windows/silverlight related and I have to do the same in .NET MVC 5.  Would have preferred some newer tech but all we got on the server is .NET 4.5 as the runtime env and it's in the red as far as space on the C drive, so upgrading to better software isn't an option.  So basically, can anyone tell me how to tell .NET MVC 5 to reuse my DB for authentication in the same manner that a silverlight app would? Essentially, it's the same concept as how I'm re-using the backend with AJAX, but I imagine some pre-packaged GUI solution for telling windows that it should hash the client password and send it to a legacy DB.  Tall order but I know they're some extremely intelligent people out there.

Comment: Some details about what mechanism your Silverlight application was using to hash the passwords would be helpful.